# Create Task extension method for mapping

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

#### What I want

We use *AutoMapper* and our whole service layer is **asynchronous**. Here is how our mapping looks currently in an API action:

```
var response = (await this.service.GetAll())
    .AsQueryable()
    .ProjectTo<DataViewModel>();
...
```

I want to achieve something like:

```
var response = await this.service
    .GetAll()
    .Map<DataViewModel>();
```

#### What I have done

The best I have achieved so far is:

```
var response = await this.service
    .GetAll()
    .Map<DataServiceModel, DataViewModel>();
```

The extension methods looking like this:

```
// Task extension
public static async Task<IEnumerable<TDestination>> MapCollection<TSource, TDestination>(
    this Task<IEnumerable<TSource>> collection)
        => (await collection)
            .MapCollection<TDestination>();

// IEnumerable extension
public static IEnumerable<TDestination> MapCollection<TDestination>(
    this IEnumerable collection)
{
    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        yield return Mapper.Map<TDestination>(item);
    }
}
```

This is acceptable, but ideally I would like to remove the dependency of `TSource` in the task extension, as it is not needed for the mapping logic.

#### Problem

If I remove `TSource` I cannot get the compiler to agree with me. When I try to use the extension defined like this:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<TDestination>> MapCollection<TDestination>(
    this Task<IEnumerable> collection)
        => (await collection)
            .MapCollection<TDestination>();
```

the compiler shouts:

> '`Task<IEnumerable<DataServiceModel>>`' does not contain definition for
>   '`MapCollection`' and the best extension method overload
>   '`TaskExtensions.MapCollection<DataViewModel>(Task<IEnumerable>)`'
>   requires a receiver of type '`Task<IEnumerable>`'

So I can't get it to recognize my method, if there is no explicit generic `TSource`. I don't understand what is the problem, since the compiler agrees with my `IEnumerable` extension, which is defined as

```
MapCollection<TDestination>(this IEnumerable collection)
```

but does not allow:

```
MapCollection<TDestination>(this Task<IEnumerable> collection)
```

#### Questions

1. Can I get around the above problem somehow and define my `Task` extension with the only generic parameter it really needs?
2. Does this usage of `Task` present any performance problems? I.e. thread blocks, deadlocks and so on. I don't think so, but I still lack in-depth knowledge of asnyc programming.

Comment: a `Task<IEnumerable<Something>>` *isn't* a `Task<IEnumerable>`. Just because two types have a particular inheritance/implementation relationship, it doesn't mean that a generic instantiated over those two types exhibits the *same* relationship.

Comment: Maybe change TSource to an object?

Comment: @Dmitriy does not work for the same reason **Damien_the_Unbeliever** stated, I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your biggest problem is *Partial Type Inference*, and it can't be done.

However if you don't mind an extra call, you could get away with and *Extension Method* and a *Wrapper Class*:

```
public class Wrapper<TSource>
{
   private readonly Task<IEnumerable<TSource>> _sourceCollection;

   public Wrapper(Task<IEnumerable<TSource>> source) 
      =>_sourceCollection = source;
      
   public async Task<IEnumerable<TDest>> To<TDest>()
      => (IEnumerable<TDest>)Mapper.Map(await _sourceCollection, _sourceCollection.GetType(), typeof(IEnumerable<TDest>));

}

public static class Extensions
{
   public static Wrapper<TSource> Map<TSource>(this Task<IEnumerable<TSource>> source)
      => new Wrapper<TSource>(source);
}
```

**Usage**

```
await service.GetAllAsync()
             .Map()
             .To<Something>();
```

<sub>***Note 1** : This is completely untested, and even if it does work lacks basic sanity checks.*</sub>

<sub>***Note 2** : This also a little wasteful with the extra layer of async.*</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will consider it. In the meantime could you please elaborate more on **Note 2**? What sort of waste are we talking about?

Comment: @Alex not much at all, every time you call await the compiler creates a class, the overhead is nothing compared to overhead if the io op. You could probably give your self an efficiency by calling ConfigureAwait(false) in the map call